# how should webpack be configured for scss files in a react app?

Tags: reactjs, sass

Let's say I have a React app with a directory structure like this:

```
- components
-- framework
--- atoms
---- atoms.scss
---- Button.js
---- ...
--- molecules
---- molecules.scss
---- FormField.js
---- ...
```

So all of the basic framework components (button, input, etc) are included in that directory.  Along with the supporting scss files for those components.  My impression is that the typical app configuration would be to configure webpack for the app so that it uses a pattern to bundle all of the nested scss file from the "framework" directory shown above.  Am I understanding that correctly?

How would I go about doing that in a React app?  I've never personally configured webpack for a React app.  Also, should that Webpack configuration and bundling process make all  scss files from the framework dir tree automatically available for all components in the app?  Ie a user-admin component in the app would be able to import the FormField component from the tree above without having to explicitly import any type of supporting scss file?  Or would some type of general import for the bundled scss still explicitly be needed for this.  Eg - import "framework.scss"?

Comment: I would recommend not using Webpack for a new project these days - look at e.g. Vite...

Comment: Despite your opinion, OP probably has good reasons to use webpack...

OP, take a look at this https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/